# Roots of a polynomial, if coefficients are not known.

Tags: polynomials

How to find the numbers of roots for a polynomial if the coefficients are not known to us?!
Take this for example $ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2 > 0$, for the fact that discriminant is $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ or simply the count of sets of $(a, b, c)$ for $D < 0$.

Comment: Check [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) to learn more about posting and writing mathematics problem on this site.

Comment: If the coefficients are not known, then what is known? A polynomial consists of its coefficients so if we know nothing about the polynomial, we essentially know nothing...

Comment: If $D>0$ there are two solutions. If $D=0$ there is one solution. If $D<0$ there are no real solutions.